# php get error to curl url from array get in file

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I get Error When Curl Data From URL ( Url From Array get in file ) .
When I use Normaly URL , It Work Correctly !
But When I get URL from Array and run a loop for it , and call function curl to run every line url , it not work ?
I don't know why , but i need someone help me .
I had turn on error report php , but nothing error !

Example File "link.txt"

```
https://www.fshare.vn/file/4UNG2NRPW5OQ
https://www.fshare.vn/file/CFTJYXKPMN7Q
https://www.fshare.vn/file/RMHD2XBFY93F
https://www.fshare.vn/file/I4TIUE6E9QOV
https://www.fshare.vn/file/5PV15EB38M7T
https://www.fshare.vn/file/ZDLJNDNWCNYM
https://www.fshare.vn/file/O1VYZUXXJNCI
https://www.fshare.vn/file/SD5C1VZ38IPN
```

And My PHP code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$lines = file('link.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // Turn Every Line To Array From File , Or use other below Method
//$lines = explode("\n",fopen('link.txt',"r")); // Other Method Get Content To Array
//$lines = explode("\n",file_get_contents('link.txt')); // Other Method Get Content To Array

foreach($lines as $key => $value){
    echo $value . "</br>"; 
    echo get_data($value); // It not Work , Why is that ? 
    echo get_data("https://www.fshare.vn/file/ACKM6ONXFZJE"); // It Work Normally
    die();
}


function get_data($url = null) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'charset' => 'utf-8'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com.vn/');
    $data           = curl_exec($ch);


    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine when I launch it. What error do you receive exactly? Can you copy&paste the error?

Comment: Don't rely on `echo` for debugging. Use `var_dump($value)` and see if there are any stray characters that might be throwing cURL off.

Comment: It show me a Blank Page !

Comment: Have you checked PHP error log? Have you checked what `curl_error` has to say?

Comment: @El_Vanja Right now it work , hmm , i don't know how to say that !

Answer (score 0):

Right now , i have tested again and it work correctly !
Don't know what happened !